# Does JSON.stringify consider sections/parent divs?

Tags: jquery, json

HTML form is divided into sections. Sections has their input fields. Right when I send the form data in JSON format like given below code. Controller receives form data as a one dimensional array.
Is there a way to send form data as two-dimensional array? Where section-name will have the array of field's name/value pair.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
                    alert('here');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('data')
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('An error has occured!! :-(')
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                })
            });
```

Comment: isn't that... `$(this).serialize()`?

Comment: Does it consider parent div/section?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav It doesn't; see my answer for an example of code that does.

Comment: Not sure how the entire page is laid out, but you can probably `.clone()` the parent section into the form as a hidden element (`.css('display', 'none')`) inside the submit function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but you can't do it with `.serializeArray()`; you'll need to walk the DOM with jQuery to assemble your data into an array formatted how you want it, and then pass that as the value of the `data` parameter to `.ajax()`. Consider the following contrived example:

```
<form>

  <div class="section">
    <span class="section_title">Section 1</span>
    <input name="this" type="text" value="this" />
    <input name="that" type="text" value="is" />
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <span class="section_title">Section 2</span>
    <input name="these" type="text" value="rather" />
    <input name="those" type="text" value="contrived" />
  </div>

</form>
```

You might walk it with the following Javascript code:

```
var formdata = {};
$('form').find('div.section')
    .each(function(i, el) {
        var sectionTitle = $(el)
            .find('span.section_title')
            .text();
        $(el).find('input')
            .each(function(i, el) {
                var name  = $(el).attr('name');
                var value = $(el).val();
                formdata[sectionTitle][name] = [value];
            });
    });
```

And the result, in `formdata`, would be:

```
{'Section 1': {'this': 'this',
               'that': 'is'},
 'Section 2': {'these': 'rather',
               'those': 'contrived'}}
```

Of course it's not tailor-made for your situation, but it should be close enough to let you get the idea; if not, feel free to comment asking for clarification and I'll do my best to provide it. (Incidentally, showing in your question an example of the HTML for the form you're working with would make it possible to provide a solution more closely applicable to your situation.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. So I need to do the reverse to load the form with values saved in this format. Right?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Pretty much, yeah -- you'd still walk the tree the same way, but instead of setting a property on `formdata`, you'd do e.g. `$('input[name=' + name + ']').val(value)`. Using JSON as your serialization format will greatly simplify this, and it's as simple as `data: JSON.stringify(formdata)` in your `.ajax()` call when saving, and then `formdata = JSON.parse("[the data your server-side code gave back]")` when loading.